# Как в QtCreator указать путь до линкера?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator, gcc, компоновщик

Как в QtCreator указать путь до линкера `mold`? Либо передать `gcc` опцию `-Bpath/to/linker`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133586/discussion-on-question-by-andrei---qtcreator----).

Answer (score 1):

Получилось только заменив исполняемый файл `/usr/bin/ld` на одноименную символическую ссылку, указывающую на мой линкер. Видимо, `ld` захардкожен в моём `gcc`, так что опция `-B=/path/to/linker` не работает.

С 12 версии GCC можно будет использовать `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-fuse-ld=mold`.

Comment: а что именно в `-B=/path/to/linker` указывал?

Comment: @Fat-Zer `/usr/lib/mold/`

Comment: и ваш линковщик находится в файле `/usr/lib/mold/ld` ? (ну, это может быть и симв. ссылка, указывающая на нужный файл).

Comment: @andrei, `/usr/lib/mold/` — это путь? а что было внутри каталога?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, там символическая ссылка

Comment: @Fat-Zer ссылка `/usr/lib/mold/ld` на `/usr/bin/mold`

Comment: @andrei, обычно линкером по умолчанию является `collect2`, а не `ld`… `gcc -dumpspecs | grep -A1 linker:` для подтвержддения… создай симлинк — может, в качестве хака заработает… но ты прав — нормальную поддержку `mold` добавят только в gcc-12… ну или можно патчик на gcc-11 накатить…

Comment: @andrei, а ещё лучше даже `ln -s /usr/bin/mold /usr/lib/mold/real-ld` — его сам `collect2` вызывает